# While debugging, can Eclipse render values in a human-readable way?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, calendar

I have a Julian day value in a `double` variable, like 2456707.5.  I want to view it while debugging as a readable calendar date string like `6 Feb 2014`.  Is there a way I can set this up in Eclipse?

More generally, is there a way to reformat a human-unreadable value in app I'm debugging, so that I can understand its value as it changes?

Comment: Oops I had it backwards.  I have a Julian day value like 2456707.5 and want to convert it to an actual calendar date like "6 Feb 2014".  Will make an edit...

Comment: The user has two questions and one is already answered, I fail to see how this can be unclear.

Comment: I tried to edit and clarify my question a moment ago, but when I do so the edit page shows "Post Closed as "unclear what you're asking" by McDowell, Andrew, Spidy, e-sushi, Nanne".

Comment: It's open now.  Yay for community moderation!

Comment: The debugger uses the class's toString() to display its contents... so it's important to provide good toString() implementations. Alas, people are often sloppy about that, or use toString() for some less-useful rendering...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several answers to the more general question "How do I view in Eclipse the current value of a variable, in a format of my choosing".  I prefer to use the Expressions view (Window > Show View > Other... > Debug > Expressions) and enter a java snippet that presents the variable the way I want.

This view is fairly powerful.  Here's a trivial example that you might be able to expand on:

```
new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd").format(java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTime())
```

Put that into the Expressions view and it'll show you today's date.  The Expressions view has full access to all variables in scope while you're debugging.

For your particular case, you'll need a class somewhere that converts the Julian Day value to a Date or time (epoch), since Java natively doesn't support the value (as far as I'm aware).  Assuming that your class is called JulianDayFormat and extends DateFormat, then you can use

```
new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy").format(new your.package.JulianDateFormat().parse(julianDayString))
```